# Can I limit the data elements received from the FB Comments Plugin?

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I'm looking to add the Comments Plugin, but wish to keep the comments simple. I'd like to have just the user-photo and comment visible. Not the date of comment, reply, like, etc.
Please advise if this is possible and how one can restrict this.
Thanks very much...
Andy

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible any more. Previously, there were ways to override comment box CSS, but these were removed with version 2 of the plugin. So, you're stuck with what Facebook provides.

It's possible to post and retrieve comments using the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/), which would allow you to style them yourself - but it would require a fair amount of technical work.